# count words and insert a tag in a variable php

Tags: php, string

i need of a function that count words content in a variable
for example:

`$comments=bla bla bla bla bla bla bla`

and starting from the first word  at 4 word for example  insert this tag: `"<!--more-->"`
 so at final i have new variable in this mode
`$comments=bla bla bla bla<!--more-->bla bla bla`

it's possible?

i have found this that appaear working i want share with you

```
function strpop($str, $word, $num=10)
  {
  if(str_word_count($str,0,'123456789') <= $num)
    return $str." ".$word;

  $tmp = array_keys(str_word_count($str,2, '123456789'));
  for($x=0; $x < sizeof($tmp)-$num; $x+=$num)
    {
    $portion .= substr($str, $tmp[$x], $tmp[($x+$num)]) . $word;
    }
  return $portion;
  }
$string = "$comments";
$word_to_add = "<!--more-->";

$newstr = strpop($string, $word_to_add);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$s="This is a very long string, here, actually really really long, or not that much.";
$toinsert="<!--more-->";

$tok=strtok($s, " ");
$s2='';
for ($i=1; $tok!==false; $i++) {
    $s2.=$tok.' '.($i == 4 ? $toinsert : '');
    $tok=strtok(" ");
}
```

`$s2` will hold your new string.

[PHP strtok()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $comments = explode(' ', $comments);
   $counter = 0;
   $out = array();
   foreach($comments as $key => $value) {
       $out[] = $value . ' ';
       if (3 == $key){
           $out[] = '"<!--more-->"';
       }
   }
   $comments = trim(implode('', $out));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is:

1) Use regular expression to extract the markup code (HTML and comments).

You see a detailed tutorial with examples about regular expression at:
http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_regular_expressions_examples-136.html

2) After extract all markup code, you can do simple explode.

That's all.

Comment: ok infact don't work but i'ma newbie this is very complex for me